# Create MNIST input with Juptyer

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to draw a digit with Jupyter Notebook and provide it as input to neural network to predict.

I used the following code to draw the pixel, not receiving the input.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
fake_img = numpy.random.random((28,28))

plt.imshow(fake_img, cmap='gray')
ax  = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()

linepoints = numpy.array([])

def onclick(event):
    print(event)
    if event.button == 3:
        global linepoints

        x = event.xdata
        y = event.ydata

        linepoints = numpy.append(linepoints, x)
        linepoints = numpy.append(linepoints, y)

        if numpy.size(linepoints) == 4:
            plt.plot((linepoints[0], linepoints[2]), (linepoints[1], linepoints[3]), '-')
            linepoints = numpy.array([])
            plt.show()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

How can I get the canvas drawable and receive the image to an array?

Comment: I do not understand the issue.The code seems to work as intended. When I run the code in a jupyter notebook, after clicking a lot in the image, the result looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlucz.png). What problem do you have running it? What is the expected outcome and in how far does it deviate from what you get?

Comment: I could not get the lines. I'm on Python 2.7. I get the panel with the 28x28 pixels. But could not get the lines. I'm trying to write a number and capture those pixels to predict. This is on the chrome browser.

Comment: Does chrome capture the right mousebutton? I can't imagine, but just to ask. Which versions of matplotlib, jupyter and IPython are you using? What operating system is this on?

Comment: I use Mac with the trackpad. I'm not seeing the click event triggering for any touch.

Comment: What is "the trackpad"? Does it have a right mousebutton or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [mac trackpad seems to have only 2 mousebuttons](https://www.howtogeek.com/267782/how-to-add-a-middle-click-to-your-macs-trackpad/), there is by default no way to use a third one for mouse interactions.

Hence you would need to use the first or second mousebutton for your interactions.

```
if event.button == 1:
```

or

```
if event.button == 2:
```

Comment: I do try to print for all buttons. (print(event)) Nothing getting printed before the if.

Comment: Since this is being run in a jupyter notebook, there is no console to print to. For interactive printing you would need to use `IPython.display.display`.

Comment: IPython.display with html helped. Thanks a lot.